# Migration of SVN to Git

Tags: git, git-svn

Im new to git. I need to migrate my repo from SVN to git with history. Im using Ubuntu 12.04 OS in my system. Please help me to do the movement.

Answer (score 2):

First, before asking, take a deeper look on [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) section of the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Also, Here is a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211405/how-to-migrate-code-from-svn-to-git-without-losing-commits-history) to your question.

Check [8.2 Git and Other Systems - Migrating to Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) section of [Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book).