# Migrate some SVN projects into existing Git repository

Tags: git, svn

We have a very large legacy solution in Visual Studio under SVN control. And there is new Git repository with code which is going to replace the legacy code. However large amount of projects (around 30) will only be changed at about 20%.

I would like to copy these into the new VS solution and also import SVN history for it. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79165/4375327)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I migrate an SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-do-i-migrate-an-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Comment: @phd - its explicitly states - existing repository - big difference.

Comment: Maybe this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9211405/4375327). Why are you saying "big difference"?

Comment: @Amessihel - not exactly. may be it is the answer but original OP concern there is to keep Git-migrated code in sync with SVN indefinitely.. I don't need that - I just need to copy them once with history and forget SVN.. The challenge is - the Git repository exists and it has its own projects which aren't in SVN at all. Idk how to make it happen..

Comment: @Amessihel - may be you right.. I need some time to figure it out.. I was hoping this was done before and get simple recipe :)