# How to change git branch output order

Tags: git, git-branch

When I type `git branch`, I receive a list of branches that appear to be sorted alphabetically instead of being sorted by their creation time.

Is there a way to make the output of `git branch` sorted by date?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514172/listing-each-branch-and-its-last-revisions-date-in-git/2514279#2514279

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: Since Git version 2.19 (late 2018), Git obeys a `branch.sort` configuration.  Since Git version 2.7.0 (early 2016), `git branch` itself allows sorting, so that you do not have to use `git for-each-ref` directly.

**Edit**

Alas there are apparent problems with the sorting options taken by `git-for-each-ref`. Since that command is (obviously) explicitely aimed at showing `refs` *and* accepts the `--sort` option, I'm thinking of this as a likely bug[1].

Here is the best options I can further come up with, but the output is quite far estranged from the original format (because they rely on decorating revisions after the fact to refer to branches). Ah well, maybe it is of use for you:

---

<sub>[1] if this were `git-rev-list` or `git-log` I would think the problem would be that we're not actually *walking* a revision tree; we're actively trying to show only *tips* of trees, without walking them.</sub>

#### Temporary alternative

```
git log --no-walk --date-order --oneline --decorate \
       $(git rev-list --branches --no-walk)
```

This would give you a list similar to

```
4934e92 (HEAD, origin/testing, origin/HEAD, testing) reviewed INSTALL file as per #1331
6215be7 (origin/maint, maint) reviewed INSTALL file as per #1331
1e5e121 (origin/emmanuel, emmanuel) buffers: adjust the size in zfsfuse_stat
e96783e (origin/compress, compress) buffers: adjust the size in zfsfuse_stat
f6e2c6c (origin/unstable, unstable) revert the fatal condition again
dd52720 (origin/master-lucid, master-lucid) lucid
3b32fa7 (tag: 0.7.0, origin/master, master) panic revocation of 0.7.0-0 package necessitates an update
6eaa64f (origin/maint-0.6.9, maint-0.6.9) Replace remount by drop_caches (on rollback)
```

_As you can see, the result can be a bit overwhelming in the presence of many remote (tracking) branches, which effectively alias the same revisions. However, the result is properly ordered by (descending) date.

#### The correct (unfortunately broken?) approach...

No, but you should be able to do

```
git for-each-ref --sort='-*committerdate' --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/
```

(*use `--sort='-*authordate'` for author date ordering*)

On my test repo, this yields:

```
compress
emmanuel
maint
maint-0.6.9
master
master-lucid
testing
unstable
```

#### Alias

you can create a git alias to do this: append the following lines to `.git/config`

```
[alias]
branch2 = git for-each-ref --sort='-*committerdate' --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/
```

From then on, you could just say `git branch2`

Comment: This is a great answer! Already +1. It doesn't work for me, however, for some reason. It does sort them differently than `git branch`, though. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: The .git/config alias tip is remarkable. I tried `--sort='-*authordate'` and `--sort='-*taggerdate'` but they none seems to do the trick of sorting by tagging time.

Comment: @WinWin, do you want them sorted by the time they were *created* or by the time they were last committed to? I'm not sure the former would be that easy to get.

Comment: @WinWin, I agree, there seems to be something preventing the sort order to work correctly. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: @ebneter Either will do for now. But none of these work for me.

Comment: @ebetner: Sorting by the time the branch was created is, in general, not just hard but impossible. If the branch creation is beyond the length of the reflog (by default 90 days), that's all you'll be able to see.

Comment: @sehe Your "Temporary alternative" works perfectly. Yes, the output is more verbose than `git branch` but I can always use `cut` or `sed` to get desired formatting. Thanks!

Comment: @sehe For example, I can get a pretty similar result by piping your output through `| cut -d " " -f  2`.

Comment: @sehe And `| cut -d "(" -f   2 | cut -d ")" -f   1` works even better. :)

Comment: @sehe One more advantage of your "Temporary alternative": It includes **tags** as well - and in order! (just like `gitk`)

Comment: @WinWin: guess what gitk uses (other than `git show-branch`) :)

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant as there is a dead simple solution in stunjo's answer

Answer (score 24):

[Stujo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54895540/5500690) is my favorite, but I wanted to go one step further and make sort by committer date my default `git branch` behavior. Here's how:

```
git config --global branch.sort -committerdate
```

Remove the `-` before `committerdate` to sort the other way.

Now `git branch` will always be sorted by date!

Comment: and how do we undo this? i.e., go back to alphabetical?

Comment: I'd recommend just resetting the git config key like this: `git config --global --unset branch.sort` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781650/5500690))

Answer (score 9):

As of git 2.7.0 this will work:

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate
```

Comment: I think this is the more accurate answer to this specific question