# Name only option for `git branch --list`?

Tags: git

`git branch` outputs a list of branches, but also outputs other human-oriented fluff such as an asterisk (`*`) beside the current branch.

```
$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at origin/master)
  branch_foo
  some/branch_bar
```

How do I get a more machine parsable output (e.g. just the name of branches) for scripting use etc.?

Comment: As a general rule for scripts, read the `git(1)` man page and use the "plumbing" commands rather than the "porcelain" commands that are usually used.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The general scripting command for working with references is `git for-each-ref`.

Branch references live in the `refs/heads/` part of the name-space, so use `git for-each-ref refs/heads` to obtain them all.

By default, `git for-each-ref` prints three items: `'%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(refname)'`,  Use a different `--format` to change this.  In this case, you probably want:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

but see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) for all the available formatting directives.  (Note also that `git for-each-ref` got a fair bit of attention in git 2.6 and 2.7: `--contains`, `--merged`, `--no-merged`, and `--points-at` are new.  In older versions of git, the first three are only available via `git branch`.)

Comment: `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads/` works for me.  Note: This adds a superfluous `refs/heads/` in front of the branch name, which may or may not be a good thing depending on the use case.

Comment: Accepting on the virtue that I prefer a solution without piping where possible.

Answer (score 16):

```
git branch --format='%(refname:short)'
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of `git show-ref --heads` is machine parsable.

```
$ git show-ref --heads
a419c3625028324901ce09533de6377740c9b551 refs/heads/branch_foo
38760602162a7e7aa7c75f1797342f3b65262999 refs/heads/some/branch_bar
```

If you just want branch names, something like this will do that:

```
$ git show-ref --heads | cut -d/ -f3-
branch_foo
some/branch_bar
```

Answer (score -1):

The following command will be a help.

`git branch -a | sed -e 's/\(^\* \|^  \)//g' | cut -d " " -f 1`