# How to log every branch last commit time?

Tags: git, logging, branch

How to log every branch last commit time?

Log the time relative today is excellent.

I know `git branch -v`  show sha1 and commit subject line for each head.

I see the commit sha1, however, I don't remember each commit time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30076212/14955

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing each branch and its last revision's date in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514172/listing-each-branch-and-its-last-revisions-date-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample how to it form one of my scripts.

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(HEAD) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) - %(color:red)%(objectname:short)%(color:reset) - %(contents:subject) - %(authorname) (%(color:green)%(committerdate:relative)%(color:reset))'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --branches --no-walk --date=relative
```

with any format options you like, maybe `--format=%cd %d %s`?