# Is it possible to prune branches on origin that haven't been touched in a certain amount of time?

Tags: git

Right now, my project (VCS: Git) has quite a few branches that haven't been touched in months. With the dynamics of this project, any branch that hasn't been updated in the last 2 months is decidedly out of date and no longer relevant.

Is there a way to prune these in bulk, given some "hasn't been touched in..." threshold?

Answer (score -1):

```
git branch
git checkout master
git branch --merged
git branch -d old-merged-feature
git branch --no-merged
git branch -D old-abandoned-feature
git remote prune origin
```

More compact:

```
comm -12  <(git branch --merged|awk '{print($1)}') <(git branch -r --merged|awk '{print($1)}'|awk -F \/ '{print($2)}')
```

See [1](https://railsware.com/blog/2014/08/11/git-housekeeping-tutorial-clean-up-outdated-branches-in-local-and-remote-repositories/)

Also try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21304578/4274360