# Sort hg branches by modification time

Tags: mercurial

When cleaning up branches in git, I have been using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21304578/1804173) to differentiate between old/inactive and new/active branches.

How can I sort all branches by their modification time in Mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a branch is just different enough in Mercurial vs Git to make this a bit tricky.  Depending on what you really want, the "trickiness" may be that it becomes completely trivial!

Start with `hg heads`, which shows all heads (see `hg help heads` for the definition of a head).  Each head is a commit, and therefore:

- has an ID;
- is in one particular branch;<sup>1</sup> and
- has a date stamp.

It also has a local revision number within *your* repository, which won't necessarily match the revision number in some clone that has the same commit.  That is:

```
$ hg heads
changeset:   5:5f5df3fc4f1c
```

Changeset `5f5df3fc4f1c` in some clone might be `4:5f5df3fc4f1c` or `100:5f5df3fc4f1c` or some such.  The number in front of the colon is the *local revision number*.

Now, the *dates* on commits are up to the machine that creates the commit, so they can be quite wildly wrong.  The local revision numbers are assigned sequentially as you add commits to your Mercurial repository, though—so if a local revision number is *higher*, that means that *you* introduced the commit *later*.  (Caveat: this could be "a lot later than actually made" if you just now brought new commits in from an old, inactive, but never-before-incorporated clone.)

In that sense, then, the output of `hg heads`, which is shown by default in reverse local-number order, is *already in the order you probably want* (or the reverse of it).  Things printed later are "less active".  So there's probably no work to do here other than to read through the output of `hg heads` (and check whether there are multiple heads within some branch).

---

<sup>1</sup>This differs from Git in that in Git, a *tip commit* is the commit to which some `refs/heads/` name points.  That tip *defines* the branch, but that commit can be in multiple branches!  The tip is necessarily a head in the Mercurial sense,<sup>2</sup> but there can only be *one* such head, because it's the branch's name that locates and thereby defines the head / tip commit, and each name identifies only one commit.

<sup>2</sup>Unless, that is, you mean `hg heads --topo`, in which case a Git commit identified by `refs/heads/name` might not be a head after all:

```
...--o--*   <-- refs/heads/midpoint
         \
          o--●   <-- refs/heads/tip
```

The commit identified by `refs/heads/tip` is a topological head while that identified by `refs/heads/midpoint` is not.  In Git the `midpoint` commit is on both branches.

---

If you do want different sortings, it's harder: instead of `hg heads`, you must use `hg log` and use a revision specifier.  Note that `-r "head() and not closed()"` produces the same output as `hg heads`, so you can start with that.  The output from `hg log` is sorted in whatever order you choose, but defaults to the same local-numeric-revision sorting.  See `hg help revisions` for more.

Comment: Using `hg heads` in combination with an output template and grepping for the current branch gives me exactly what I want. If someone else needs this: `hg heads --template '{node|short} {pad(branch, 80)} [rev: {rev}] {fill(desc, \"50\")|firstline}\n' | grep -E "$|\`hg branch\`" --color=always | less`