# Command to List Remote Active Branches only (bitbucket)

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

[image: Image is listing only active branches, need command for the same on terminal]

I have tried using **git branch -r --no-merged** but may have branches which were never merged. So, need to list only active remote branches and not all remote branches. Please share command for the same.

Comment: Note that Git itself has no notion of "active" or "inactive" branches. GitHub and Bitbucket have both made up their own (probably slightly different) definitions for these.

Answer (score 0):

Considering even the [BitBucket API listing branches](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/branches) does not mention any "active" attributes, that particular feature (list of active branches) is likely to not be readily available.

You would need to [fetch and display each branch last commit date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59297569/6309), to determine which one were "recently" updated:

```
git fetch && \
git branch -av --format='\''%(authordate)%09%(authordate:relative)%09%(refname)'\'
```