# Git show branch names with a commit between two dates

Tags: git

I would like to get a list of all git branches, which have the head (most recent) commit between two dates, in a format like this (for purposes of checking and deleting old branches):

```
$ [Command to list all remote branch names between 2023-11-28 and 2023-11-30]:

branchName1 2023-11-30
branchName2 2023-11-28
branchName3 2023-11-28
```

I have tried using `git branch -r --sort=committerdate --list` and it's close, returning a list of all branches without dates. However I don't know the syntax well enough to modify this to include the dates, and perform the filter.

Please can you let me know the correct edits to this command (or a better git command to use) to achieve a result like the list above?

Comment: If you have the branch names, then a little bit of bash-fu can be handy. Just pipe the branch names into a `while` so that you take a branch and get the date (author or commit) of the tip commit of that branch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693888/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/21304578/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+branches+date