# Git auto-tracking branches from a clone

Tags: git

I have a git bare repo that I manage and I want to have git auto create tracking branches for all the remote branches.  That way no one has to auto create them.

I tried to do it in a post fetch hook, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches help (in a hook)?

Comment: I'm dying to get this working as well :) I assume you mean this should be done so no one has to manually create them.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Git 1.6.6, the "git fetch [remote]" command will create remote-tracking branches for all branches in the remote repository.