# Why do I have problems pushing new branches to my Git repository?

Tags: git, branch, git-push, git-clone

As a followup to [my question about unavailable branches after svn to git migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012613/how-do-i-list-and-fetch-remote-branches-after-svn-to-git-migration), I have a different problem: I'm unable to push new branches to my central Git repository.

```
$ git clone ssh://server/opt/git/our_app.git
$ cd our_app
$ git branch my-test-branch
$ git checkout my-test-branch
$ echo test > test.txt
$ git add test.txt
$ git commit test.txt -m "test commit"
[master ed81ec0] test commit
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 test.txt
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

So, this does not push my branch to the server.  A colleague advised me to look into my .git/config, which looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://server/opt/git/our_app.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I was adviced to manually add a push entry:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://server/opt/git/our_app.git
    push = refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

Now things looked better:

```
$ git push
Password: 
Counting objects: 1, done.
Delta compression using up to 1 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 5 bytes, done.
Total 1 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://server/opt/git/our_app.git
 * [new branch]      my-test-branch -> my-test-branch
```

While this worked, it still feels like a hack.  What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: The default behavior for `git push` is to push branches that have matching destinations in existence on the remote end. New branches don't have such matching destinations. You can change the default behavior with the `push.default` config variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To push a new branch use `git push origin my-test-branch`

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to push your branch with the same branch name then just use

```
git push origin my-test-branch
```

If you want your changes to appear on the master branch of the origin repo:

```
git push origin my-test-branch:master
```

Answer (score 4):

You can push a branch to a remote repository with

`git push origin my-test-branch`

You can then view all remote branches with

`git branch -r`

[Here's an introduction](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html) to creating/removing remote branches.