# switching remotes in github

Tags: github

Can we switch to different remotes in github  I have two remotes

upstream (main repo)
origin (mywork)

Accidently, i created clone of upstream and created branches and worked in it. I want to miove all changes made to upstream's test branch to origin and also switch to origin. Now when ever I create a branch it is created in origin

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering those are the same repo (or at least repos with a common history), you can:

- clone the other GitHub repo 'origin' '`mywork`'on your computer
- add the first repo (the 'upstream' cloned one locally) as a remote (`git add remote upstream file:///path/to/main/repo`)
- fetch everything and create [local branches out of the remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches/6300386#6300386)
- push everything back to your origin 'mywork' repo