# Git: how can git/linux maintainers maintain so many branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, gitk

Personally, if I look at the git or the linux repo with gitk, I am totally overwhelmed by the huge amount of merges/branched. I have absolutely no clue what is going on.

I assumed that in general you try to have an as linear history as possible and only a few branches (e.g. master, maint, next, pu - thats it) in the *public* repo. I.e. I assumed that merges are seldom and mostly rebase is used. Apparently I am wrong.

1. I wonder what the git/linux  maintainers do to have a good easy overview
2. Why don't they use rebase more often and have much more branches than only master, maint, next pu?

Comment: Branches are cheap so they are taken advantage of often :)

Comment: In 2007 [Google Tech Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8) Linus Torvalds gives some examples of how he uses git, particularly on kernel and git itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There one very important thing to understand in relationship with Git and rebase.

```
Do not rebase commits that you have pushed to a public repository.
```

During the time you are working on a merge locally you can use rebase as much often as you like, cause it's local. If you like a linear histroy. In other words you won't see the rebase work they did.

The other part about the number of branches is simply a kind of experience and more than that a question of concept. I have done branching with over 300 branches in parallel..which is only a kind taming the beast by using conventions and a good concept.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a kernel developer, and certainly can not speak for them.  [Here's](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Git_Management) a reference where Linus talked about it some, that I think answers your questions.  I will add that having lots of *random* branches is confusing, but imposing a little order on it makes it *easier* to have branches IMHO. (Examples of order might be naming topic branches as `topic/short_name`, including meaningful commit messages, devs keep some external documentation and actually talk to each other, or whatever is appropriate for your environment.)

I'll also include a reference to [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow, since it is practally required Git reading, and applies to your question.

Comment: +1 for link to that Git workflow. That is singularly the best Git explanation I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that, when you are cloning a git repo, you may get all the remote branches, but you only create and checkout *one* local branch (usually `master`, tracking `remotes/origin/master`)

(This is why you have questions like "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)")

Depending on your topic of interest, you would only checkout and track one specific branch, do some work, and rebase regularly your local branch on top of `origin/branch` to keep your work up-to-date.

You won't merge from the official public branches to your branch: that would be a back-merge, and they should be avoided, as illustrated in "[What is the right git workflow with shared feature branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927566/what-is-the-right-git-workflow-with-shared-feature-branches/12927985#12927985)".

Answer (score 0):

Check out Greg K-H [Ask a kernel developer](https://lwn.net/Articles/512720/) column: he explains his workflow in detail. Greg used to be the maintainer of the stable branch; he is the current maintainer for many subsystems, including USB.