# What is the right git workflow with shared feature branches?

Tags: git

Say I have a branch named `feature` that has been branched off `master`. Both, developer1 and developer2 checkout `feature`. developer1 commits a change to `feature` and pushes it. Then developer3 pushes something to `master`. At this point `master` and `feature` diverge, each having a separate commit.

What's the right way to go about getting the latest from `master` into the `feature`, if there are conflicts? Should I rebase `master` into the `feature`, or merge it in?

**EDIT:**

I should mention that in this case I would not want to rewrite the history on developer2. Because that would be bad. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering `feature` branch is already shared, it shouldn't be rebased on `master` (as it changes its - shared - history).

A simple merge from `master` to `feature` will be enough (without speculating as why `dev3` pushed to `master` in the first place).

---

As [Adam Dymitruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217284/adam-dymitruk) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927566/what-is-the-right-git-workflow-with-shared-feature-branches/12927985#comment17539646_12927985), this is called a "back-merge", and, depending on the role you attribute to `master`, it is questionable: if `master` represents the stable production state, you should merge *to* `master`, not *from* `master`.

But again, my answer made no assumption on said role.

---

This is why the famous **[git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)** illustrates in its [blog post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) merges which are coming *to* master (from, for instance, an `hotfix` branch, as I [commented earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927566/what-is-the-right-git-workflow-with-shared-feature-branches/12927985#comment17519985_12928245))

[image: git flow]

Comment: back-merges are not good. No matter why the other dev committed to master.

Answer (score 2):

`git` is a great tool; but, it *cannot* take the place of good communication among developers.

You have to ask whether the changes in `master` *must* also be included in `feature`.  Ideally, a *feature branch* should have the smallest amount of code possible.

If the change(s) absolutely must be included in `feature`, then the you have basically two options: `git rebase`; and, `git cherry-pick`.  I suppose you could perform a backward merge from `master` into `feature`; but, that can lead to bad situations...

`cherry-pick` allows you to apply a specific commit or multiple commits to the current `HEAD`, keeping comment and author information.  After having successfully `cherry-pick`ed, git is smart enough to know that the two commits are the same when merging `feature` back into `master`.  If it's just a few commits we're talking about, then `cherry-pick` should be sufficient.

`rebase` allows you to apply the current branch (line of commits) starting from a different point in history.  As you pointed out, this can be troublesome for developer1 and developer2 who already have copies of `feature`.  They would also need to `rebase` their local development onto the *new* `feature` branch.

At any rate, the commit directly to `master` by developer3 should have been in its own feature branch, and that feature branch should have been merged.  That feature branch could then have been merged into `feature` as necessary.  Assuming just one (the most recent) commit in `master`, you could rectify the situation as follows:

```
# Ensure clean working directory
$ git stash

# Create new branch at master
$ git branch some-descriptive-name master

# Move master back one commit
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard HEAD^

# Merge the new branch into master
$ git merge --no-ff some-descriptive-name

# Forcibly update master
#   YOU SHOULD COMMUNICATE WITH OTHER DEVS BEFORE DOING THIS
$ git push -f origin master

# Merge the new branch into feature
$ git checkout feature
$ git merge --no-ff some-descriptive-name
```

I cannot stress enough how valuable good communication is because these kinds of "oops" things can and do happen all the time.

Good luck!

**EDIT:**

The part about `cherry-pick`ing was written with the assumption that there was only a few commits (or just one) to `master` and that they all would be `cherry-pick`ed.

```
x -- y (master)
 \
  a -- b -- c (feature)
```

Comment: I don't like cherry-picking because of its limitation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112), duplicating dev3 commit. I would prefer a merge here.

Comment: I understand, but why cherry-pick said commits, duplicating them on `feature` branch, and making a future merge of `feature` back to merge potentially more problematic?

Comment: If you merge from master (reverse merge), you include *all* commits.  This leads to very lengthy `bisect`s and the feature branch is no longer just the feature.  Your point about cherry-picking is very valid.  But, I think that performing surgery on `master` is the best way to handle the situation.

Comment: True. But in this instance, we are talking about *one* commit, right?

Comment: Point taken ;)  But, I still don't like the line going from `master` to `feature` :P

Comment: Interesting: that (the line from master to feature) somehow doesn't bother me. As suspect the merge should have been done from an `hotfix` branch to `feature` (as illustrated in http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), instead of `master` to `feature`: I just don't know from where `dev3` did his/her commit.

Answer (score 1):

the third developer should not be writing a feature on master. The rare exception is a hotfix. But even then, it should be it's own branch then merged with `--no-ff` onto master. I've written a long post about branch per feature here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/