# Git checkout remote branch of a remote repository

Tags: git, refspec

When git clone some repository then it retrieves all branches from it:

```
git clone https://github.com/android/platform_build.git build1
cd build1/ && git branch -a && cd ..
```

then, when I use `build1` as a mirror and clone it, I do not see all its remote branches (I see only `build1`'s local master branch)

```
git clone build1 build2
cd build2 && git branch -a && cd ..
```

How can I checkout remote of remote branches ?

I know that I can checkout all remote branches in build1 mirror with command

```
cd build1 && for remote in `git branch -r `; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)
but what if I do not have access to build1 directory ?

Also, there is `git ls-remote origin` command which shows all remote refs, but is there any elegant way to checkout those remote of remote branches ?

Comment: Can i suggest instead of `https://` using `git://`?  Fetching is much more efficient for both you and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you clone `build1` to `build2`, `build1` is `build2`'s `origin`, and `build2` knows nothing about `https://github.com/android/platform_build.git` , which is where the "remote" branches live.  One solution may be to add `https://github.com/android/platform_build.git` as a remote in the configuration of `build2`.  To add a remote called `github`:

```
git remote add github https://github.com/android/platform_build.git
```

Then run a `fetch` to get the remote branches:

```
git fetch github
```

Now, when you run `git branch -a` you should see branches prefixed with `remotes/github/` that correspond with those prefixed with `remotes/origin` in `build1`.

On the other hand, `build2` should have a remote branch for each local branch in `build1`, including those that are tracking remote branches from `build1`'s perspective.  For example, if there is a branch named `foo` on github, it will show up as `remotes/origin/foo` in `build1`.  If you set up a local branch to track that remote branch in `build1` also called `foo`, then `build2` should have a `remotes/origin/foo` as well.  Then, when `foo` is updated in `build1` by fetching/merging changes from github's `foo`, those changes should show up in `build2` after a `fetch`/`pull`.