# Importing github project to bitbucket

Tags: github, bitbucket

I imported my github project to bitbucket following this tutorial :

[tutorial import github project to bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project#Importingcodefromanexistingproject-UploadingorpushingaGitorMercurialprojecttoanemptyrepository)

Worked great except that I want to import all my branches, so I did the :

```
git branch -a
```

and I get this as a result :

```
master
planB
stuffOnTheNewBranch
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/pageflipStuff
remotes/origin/planB
remotes/origin/stuffOnTheNewBranch
```

After pushing all, when I check on bitbucket, only `master`, `planB`, `stuffOnTheNewBranch` are imported ... How to push all the branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would push all the *local* branches, not the ones declared in the `remotes` namespace.

If you want to push all the branches coming from the remote `origin`, you must first create a local branch for each of the `origin` branches.
For that, see "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches/6300386#6300386)".