# What are the nameless heads and how do they occur when I configure to pull * from * in git?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I tried to get a remote branch in github into my eclipse and ended up using configure fetch from upstream option in eclipse with * as a value in local and remote branch name fields.

As expected it pulled all the remote branches into my local repository remote tracking section alongside a bunch of numbered brand heads such as

```
origin/refs/pull/1/head
```

In all about 30 of them with older commits.

In my github repo I have none of those visible.

Can you help me understand what are these remote branches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those (`refs/pull/x`) are pull requests.

See GitHub page on "[Checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)"

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

> The remote `refs/pull/` namespace is read-only. If you try to push any commits there, you'll see this error:

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/pull/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.local:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git'
```