# Export the issues from gitLab to github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

We have shifted to github(enterprise) to github. So now I want to have my all issues to export from gitlab and import to github. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the best way is to use the API from gitlab and GitHub. And create a small script that will forward all issues to GitHub. I never tried this, but you can check this out: https://github.com/piceaTech/node-gitlab-2-github

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265837/transfer-git-repositories-from-gitlab-to-github-can-we-how-to-and-pitfalls-i