# Github: There isn't anything to compare

Tags: git, github

I have repo at gitlab. I want to move it to github with the same commits. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer git repositories from GitLab to GitHub - can we, how to and pitfalls (if any)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265837/transfer-git-repositories-from-gitlab-to-github-can-we-how-to-and-pitfalls-i)

Comment: You can find the your solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266000/9134576)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to clone the git repo to your computer. change the uplink URL after pulling has been completed, and then you need to push it back to the new repo.

You have two potential answers in the comment section of your question for more information.