# Gitlab fork option greyed out

Tags: windows, git, github, gitlab

The fork option is greyed out for me I have developer access what do I do?

[image]

I’m told for importing to github to look for the project url e.g

[image]

I also don't see that button in the first image do I have to fork first?   Also, if so do pulls using github desktop automatically pull to the main branch in gitlab, or do I need to pull in gitlab as well.

What is the least technical way of using gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

The fork option in your project probably been disabled. This setting can be changed in the Project:

`Settings -> General -> Visibility, project features, permissions`

However you need to be a **Maintainer** or above.

[image: project settings]

If you want to import a GitLab project to GitHub, see [Transfer git repositories from GitLab to GitHub - can we, how to and pitfalls (if any)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265837/transfer-git-repositories-from-gitlab-to-github-can-we-how-to-and-pitfalls-i)