# How to see the 'http' adress of Git repository in use from RStudio?

Tags: r, git, gitlab, rstudio

I have started to use version control in RStudio using GitLab, but now I wish to use GitHub instead. So, I need to move all of my repositories from GitLab to GitHub, as specified e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265837/transfer-git-repositories-from-gitlab-to-github-can-we-how-to-and-pitfalls-i).

But, for some time, I was using both GitHub and GitLab simulteneously, and developing single project on both repos individually! Quite stupid, but it happens..

Shortly, now I need know, **which repo (GitHub or GitLab) is my R studio using?** I am looking for some code that will print out the http of the repository in use?

something like `repo.print` and will return the http associated: `https://gitlab.com/xx/yy/z` or `https://github.com/xx/yy/z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git config --get remote.origin.url` in Terminal or

```r
shell("git config --get remote.origin.url")
```

in R console / script.