# How should I move a hosted git repo to a new host?

Tags: git, tfs

I have a TFS hosted git repo (e.g. https://tfsfoo.com/_git), and I need to move it to another TFS host (e.g. https://tfsbar.com/_git)

My solution is to do the following (modified based on suggestion below to use --mirror):

1. git clone https://tfsfoo.com/_git/proj --mirror
2. Loop through branches (git branch -r) and then git branch --track each of those (as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891794/git-pull-all-branches-from-remote-repository/18911322#18911322))
3. Note that I had already pushed to the new repo (without branches), so --mirror wasn't an option.
4. git pull
5. git remote set-url origin https://tfsbar.com/_git/proj
6. git push --all --follow-tags

Now - I know I can just try this to see if it works (and I probably will while I wait for answers), but given that there are multiple ways to do just about everything in git, I'm wondering if there's a better way - or more importantly, if there's anything wrong with this approach (I'm relatively new to git).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have network access to the second server, then yes, pushing is the easiest way.

To create local branches for all remote tracking branches, you can use the one-liner I usually use at "[git pull all branches from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911322/6309)".

The alternative is to [`git clone --mirror`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the first repo, and push it to the second server [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18336145/6309).

Comment: ahh - I didn't know about --mirror (nor did I find the first link in my search, as this is probably a duplicate of that question).

Comment: @Alan no, your question illustrates the alternative technique, when you stay in the same local repo (instead of making a bare repo with the `git clone --mirror`)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [git-copy](https://github.com/cybertk/git-copy).

```
git copy https://tfsfoo.com/_git https://tfsbar.com/_git
```