# Run command git branch --set-upstream-to produce error

Tags: git

I tried to execute command:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/master
fatal: branch 'origin/master' does not exist
```

I checked origin/master exists

Comment: `origin/master` is a "remote branch", and remote branches do not *have* "upstreams".  Normally they *are* upstreams; normally you'd set `master` (a local branch) to have `origin/master` (remote branch) as its upstream.  Is that what you meant to do?

Answer (score 7):

The syntax for [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) is:

```
git branch' (--set-upstream-to=<upstream> | -u <upstream>) [<branchname>]
```

In your case:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master 
# or
git branch -u origin/master master

# for git older than 1.8
git branch master --set-upstream origin/master
```

If you see an error like:

```
Error is: fatal: 
Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'origin/master' is not a branch.
```

It means you haven't fetched anything from the remote `origin`.

1. Check that you do have a remote named origin, with a proper associated url

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```
2. Try and fetch from origin

   ```
   git fetch origin
   ```

You can see more about the fetch process in "[After `git update remote` the new upstream branches are visible but not `origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105819/6309)".

Comment: @SergiiBezgin What error message do you see? And what version of Git are you using?

Comment: Error is: fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'origin/master' is not
a branch.

Answer (score 4):

Usually after doing a git init and then also creating a repository in Github, the next thing I want to do is set my remote **origin** and tie my remote branch to my local master branch.

```
git init
git remote add origin <repository_url>
git fetch
```

Now, when I enter

```
 git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

I get the error: fatal: branch 'master' does not exist

So, I did a

```
git branch -a
```

and found only

**remotes/origin/master**

Since I was in a newly created git repository, I did a simple

```
git checkout master
```

After this, git branch -a showed me the local master branch along with the remote,

- **master**

  remotes/origin/master

After this

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

gave no error and my local master branch was set to track the remote master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while searching for

```
"fatal: branch 'integration/release/February' does not exist"
```

but the reason for the error in my case was different.

I "set upstream" enough that I'd made a bash alias for it, but when I tried to use the alias I introduced a space that meant the command I was sending was

```
git branch --set-upstream-to= integration/release/February
```

whereas what I needed, obviously, was

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=integration/release/February
```