# Update branch in my local github repository from remote repository

Tags: git, github

I forked a github repository to my local github account and was working on the master branch for sometime. After this the original repository had a new branch created which is not there in my local forked repository. I normally update my local repository using "git pull upstream master".
Now I want to work on the new branch created in the original repository and wondering how do I update my local repository to add the new branch.

Comment: `git fetch upstream`, `git checkout new-branch`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After git update remote the new upstream branches are visible but not origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105784/after-git-update-remote-the-new-upstream-branches-are-visible-but-not-origin)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+new+branch+from+upstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `git fetch upstream` to make sure you have a local copy of the most recent versions of the remote refs (branches). This is implicitly done each time you `git pull upstream` anyway, but it can't hurt to check again before creating your local branch)

Then you can create your local instance of the branch with `git checkout <branchName>`.

If you're unsure about the branch name, check it in the output of `git branch -r` which lists the list of branches you updated with the earlier `fetch`.

However, don't checkout the remote branch but the local counterpart.

For example : NOT `git checkout remotes/origin/my_branch` which would end up in a detached HEAD state pointing to the commit this remote ref happened to point to. What you want to checkout is `git checkout my_branch` if your config sets upstream automatically, adding the option `--set-upstream-to=remotes/origin/my_branch` if it's not the case.

Comment: That was an unexpected acceptance, 5 years later! Never too late, though.