# how to get all branches of my forked git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, git-clone

I have cloned, pulled and fetched my remote git repo at BitBucket. But I could only get the master branch. My repo at BitBucket has 4 branches:

- master
- fix/cleanup
- etc/schema_note
- feature/sampledata

[image]

I have found the two questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches). I followed some of the instructions in those questions.
When I tried `git branch -a`, I could not see the other three branches.

```
*master  
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master  
 remotes/origin/master
```

I tried `git checkout origin/fix/cleanup`. I got an error message.

> error: pathspec 'origin/fix/cleanup` did not match any file(s) known
>   to git.

I tried `checkout -b`, but got another error.

```
$ git checkout -b fix/cleanup origin/fix/cleanup
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'fix/cleanup' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/fix/cleanup' which can not be resolved as com
mit?
```

I also tried to execute the oneliner.

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

But it gave me the new branches **origin/HEAD** and **origin/master** in my local, not for the other 3 branches. What is going on my repo?

I tried `git fetch --all` and `git pull --all`. They gave me nothing changed.

Comment: If you cloned the repo, you already have all (remote) branches.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25663746/6309

Comment: @VonC I don't think that's the answer, here. The remote branches in question are not even listed in the output of `git branch -a`...

Comment: @Jubobs true... some `git fetch` should update that.

Comment: @VonC But the OP writes: *I have cloned, pulled and fetched my remote git repo*. It doesn't add up...

Comment: @Sithu Is your repository public, by any chance?

Comment: @Jubobs that can happen if you clone a cloned repo. First clone has all the remote branches, but the clone of the clone would have only master.

Comment: @VonC Really? How? I thought clones were all equal... Well, aside from unreachable objects that don't get transmitted.

Comment: @Jubobs a clone, yes. But a clone of a clone, no.

Comment: @VonC I'm intrigued. Can you think of a relevant link that would tell me more?

Comment: @Jubobs not really, but it is easy to test: clone a repo which has a lot of branches, then clone that clone: the `refs/remotes` namespace isn't clone. Only `refs/heads`

Comment: could [git namespaces](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces.html) be relevant here?

Comment: @jubobs my repo is private and fork.

Comment: Orignally, I cloned it using `--depth 1`. Please check http://goo.gl/o0LQeq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch all remote branches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957760/how-to-fetch-all-remote-branches)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I eventually found a fix. I tweaked the git config file.
I changed

`fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

to

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Then, `$ git fetch --all` worked for the changes.

```
Fetching origin
Password for 'https://myusername@bitbucket.org':
remote: Counting objects: 993, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (581/581), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (966/966), 723.76 KiB | 8.00 KiB/s, done.
emote: Total 966 (delta 324), reused 964 (delta 322)Resolving deltas:   0% (0/32

Resolving deltas: 100% (324/324), completed with 21 local objects.
From https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myproj
 * [new branch]      etc/schema_note -> origin/etc/schema_note
 * [new branch]      feature/sampledata -> origin/feature/sampledata
 * [new branch]      fix/cleanup -> origin/fix/cleanup
```

Now, `$ git branch -a` started to list all remote branches;

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/etc/schema_note
  remotes/origin/feature/sampledata
  remotes/origin/fix/cleanup
  remotes/origin/master
```

Finally, I `checkout` for every branch.

```
TPP@SITHU /d/xampp/htdocs/myproj (master)
$ git checkout etc/schema_note
Branch etc/schema_note set up to track remote branch etc/schema_note from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'etc/schema_note'

TPP@SITHU /d/xampp/htdocs/myproj (etc/schema_note)
$ git checkout feature/sampledata
Branch feature/sampledata set up to track remote branch feature/sampledata from
origin.
Switched to a new branch 'feature/sampledata'

TPP@SITHU /d/xampp/htdocs/myproj (feature/sampledata)
$ git checkout fix/cleanup
Branch fix/cleanup set up to track remote branch fix/cleanup from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'fix/cleanup'
```

Here is my final repo branch list:

```
$ git branch -a
  etc/schema_note
  feature/sampledata
* fix/cleanup
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/etc/schema_note
  remotes/origin/feature/sampledata
  remotes/origin/fix/cleanup
  remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: You must have originally cloned using the `--single-branch` or `--depth` parameter to get that fetch line.

Comment: @onionjake exactly what happened in my case!

Answer (score 1):

If you cloned the repo, you should already have all remote branches.

The way git works is every copy of the repository is basically the same. The moment you clone a repo, you get everything the remote server has, including all history.

If you see branches in one place but not another, (e.g. on one client but not another), then it can only mean:

1. There are branches local to one location that hasn't been propagated to the remote server

   and/or
2. The local client hasn't fetched/pulled the propagated changes

**edit**

actually, could [git namespaces](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces.html) be relevant here?