# Importing from Bitbucket to Stash with history?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, bitbucket-server

We are moving our repositories from Bitbucket to our local environment in Stash. I am able to import the latest version of our repositories but not the details of previous commits and versions.

Can you please guide me what I should do to import our repositories with all branches, commits and version details?

This is how we are importing our repositories:

1. Create a folder on local, using Tortise Git, clone it.
2. Open Git Bash, go to this folder(directoary) by changing path using CD command
3. Run the following commands:
       git init

   ```
   git add --all

   git commit -m "Initial Commit"  

   git remote add origin http://User@localhost:7990/scm/PROJECT/repo.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```

As I'm new to Git, these may not be the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

- clone the Bitbucket repo
- create a local branch for all Bitbucket branches
- push everything to Stash.

That would means:

```
git clone -o bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/username/reponame
cd reponame
remote=bitbucket ; for brname in `git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | awk '{gsub(/[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do git branch --set-upstream-to $brname  $remote/$brname ; done
git remote add origin http://User@localhost:7990/scm/PROJECT/repo.git
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Couple of notes:

- I have named the remote for the Bitbucket repo '`bitbucket`', instead of the default '`origin`'.
  That is because you will end up working with your Stash repo **by default**.
  That is why I reserved the remote name "`origin`" for said Stash repo.
- Making a local branch for every bitbucket branches is described here: "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309)".
- I wouldn't recommend working in that local repo (which is tracking all Bitbucket branches).
  I would rather cloned the newly filled Stash repo elsewhere, and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

To import the project files, commit history etc, you can do something like:

```
git clone --bare git@bitbucket.org:/login/myrepo.git
cd myrepo.git
git push --mirror git@stash.acme.com:/project/myrepo.git
cd ..
rm -rf myrepo.git
```