# Merge multiple git repositories into one, keeping branches history

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, git-subtree

I have four separate projects. They have their own git repository. and the same name of branches for all projects.

```
 /project/
 /project/projA/
 /project/projA/.git/
 /project/projB/
 /project/projB/.git/
 /project/projC/
 /project/projC/.git/
 /project/projD/
 /project/projD/.git/
```

All git repositories have the same name of branches, and of course their own master branch.

## Question

I would like to merge all projects into one like so:

```
  /Project/.git/
  /project/projA/
  /project/projB/
  /project/projC/
  /project/projD/
```

### But

i want to keep the history of all branches.

ps -> i have the same name of branches for all repo.
for exemple: a branche name used for all four project: V6-004

### Details

I tried ***submodule*** and ***subtree*** but the both doesn't solve the issue.

I tried also this.

```
  $ mkdir new_parent_project
  $ cd new_parent_project
  $ git init
  # Now we need to create the initial commit. This is essential.
  $ touch README.md
  $ git add README.md
  $ git commit -am "initial commit"
```

after

```
  # merge project ProjA into subdirectory ProjA
  $ git remote add -f ProjA http://GitUrl
  $ git merge -s ours --no-commit ProjA/V6-006
  $ git read-tree --prefix=ProjA/ -u ProjA/V6-006
  $ git commit -m "merging ProjA into subdir: ProjA"
```

after

```
  # merge project ProjB into subdirectory ProjB 
  $ git remote add -f ProjB http://GitUrl
  $ git merge -s ours --no-commit ProjB/V6-006
  $ git read-tree --prefix=ProjB/ -u ProjB/V6-006
  $ git commit -m "merging ProjB into subdir: ProjB"
```

### but

the projects are merged but i have only the history of V6-006. but i don't have history for the others branches.

Comment: "I tried submodule and subtree but the both doesn't solve the issue."... too bad: submodule is one easy solution in this instance.

Comment: yes but. This model works well when you want to include a third-party library in your project that only occasionally needs to be updated.On the other hand, if you use a submodule for a tightly-coupled library to which you will often be making changes, you will find that submodules are not the answer.

Comment: Do you have only one branch (`master`) per subrepo to get into your repo? Or do those subrepos have multiple branches of their own? (in addition of their `master`)

Comment: yeah those subrepos have multiple branches of their own.

Comment: You just want all the existing history on individual branches and in subdirs, and then a giant octopus merge at the end bringing everything together?

Comment: @AnasZAHOURI Hi, I'm going thought something similar. Did you manage to solve it in sane way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That solution is not so far from what you tried.
This works only if your different projects have no common files (otherwise it can be difficult to solve conflicts)

```sh
# create a new repo:
git init all_projects
cd all_project
# to make it more easy to understand, let's create a new branch
git checkout -b main

# import 1st project
git remote add projectA http://projectA
git fetch --all --tags
git checkout masterA projectA/master
git rebase masterA main
# move the main branch to the current state
git branch main -f
# Now your branch main is at the same state as your A project

# import 2st project
git remote add projectB http://projectB
git fetch --all --tags
git checkout masterB projectB/master
git rebase masterB main
# move the main branch to the current state
git branch main -f
# Now your branch main contains all commits from projectA and projectB

# etc..
```

The result will be a repository with 1st all commits from project A, then all commits from project B, even if the project B has some commits dated before the last commit of project A, but this should not be a problem (and the history tree will be easier to read)

**EDIT :** Sorry I just notice this not solve your problem to get all remote branches. Maybe you can find a solution based on [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches), with something like this:

```sh
for i in $(git branch -r |grep projectA|awk -F'/' '{print $2}'); do
  git checkout $i projectA/$i
  git rebase $i main
done
```

but this would make your tree more complex because all branches will starts from the `main` commit ..

Comment: I cannot get it to work, it gives an error on step `git checkout masterA projectA/master` saying that `error: pathspec "masterA" did not match any files known to git`. What should I put in "masterA"?

Comment: if git consider `masterA` as a file, that probably means that branch does not exists locally (neither remotely I suppose). Or maybe `git fetch` is missing

Comment: @Asenar Do you have any idea what to do for two repositories that *do* share common files, namely one being a fork of the other without history? I'm [trying to figure this out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508600/how-do-i-combine-two-git-repositories-one-a-snapshot-of-the-other-with-current).

Comment: Will this work when there are NO remote HTTP repos, but only local files?

Comment: @przemo_li remote repo can have url starting `http`, `user@server` or `/path/to/loca/dir`, so I don't see why this would not works. but you can check `git help clone` to see some interresting options (--no-hardlinks, --shared, …)

Comment: I don't think this works, because masterA is required to  end up in a subdirectory; now the merge and rebase only adds files to the main directory.