# How can I merge 2 git repositories?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch

I have two git repositories, say project1 and project2, and project2 is located in a subfolder of project1 :

```
/project1/.git (with contents of project2/ ignored)
/project1/project2/.git
```

I would like to know how I can merge project2 into project1, with the same folder structure, but keeping the history of project2 ?

I there a simple solution for that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple git repositories into one, keeping branches history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502970/merge-multiple-git-repositories-into-one-keeping-branches-history)

Comment: In my case, the two git repos are not at the same folder level

Comment: Are there branches in project2 and if yes, are you concerned with the history of those branches as well?

Comment: Yes, there are branches in project2. However, only one of them is really of interest for merging project2 into project1.

Comment: This was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6426247/2303202 I guess what you need is what is written after EDIT2 there: "git merge -sours --no-commit ... && git read-tree --prefix=... -u ... && git commit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I moved project2 into a temporary folder, then :

```
git subtree add -P project2 ~/tmp_project2 PROJECT2_BRANCH
```

did the job very well.

Answer (score 2):

I would just first move everything inside `project2` into a subdirectory and then simply merge thus modified repository of `project2` into `project1`.

Assuming that you want to merge the contents and history of the branch `PROJECT2_BRANCH` in `project2` as a submodule into the branch `PROJECT1_BRANCH` in `project1`:

```
git clone /project1/project2 ~/tmp_project2
cd ~/tmp_project2
git checkout PROJECT2_BRANCH
mkdir project2
# The following line requires bash, it will not work in a POSIX shell.
# It basically "git mv"s into project2 everything except .git and project2
git ls-tree --name-only -z HEAD|{ while read -d '' f; do git mv "$f" project2; done; }
git commit -m "Moved everything into a new subdirectory project2"

git clone /project1 ~/project1_merged_with_project2
cd ~/project1_merged_with_project2
git checkout PROJECT1_BRANCH
git remote add proj2 ~/tmp_project2
git pull proj2 PROJECT2_BRANCH

git remote remove proj2
rm -rf ~/tmp_project2
```

Comment: OK, understood. I will try this. Thanks