# Multiple .git files in one git repository with history

Tags: git, github, devops, github-for-windows

I have a local directory containing files with multiple git files within.
example

Project/folder1/.git

Project/folder2/.git

and so on

Is there a way of merging these .git files into one and pushing to git and having the commit history intact?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple git repositories into one, keeping branches history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502970/merge-multiple-git-repositories-into-one-keeping-branches-history)