# how to create local branches for all remote branches in GIT

Tags: git, git-branch

How to create local branches for all the remote branches available

I can able to create a local branch from a remote branch one by one.

Is there any command available to create local branches from all the remote branches available.

(example: i have 50 branches in remote, i wants to create 50 local branches for those remote branches)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track all remote git branches as local branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)

Comment: What for? Maybe there is a simpler way of whatever you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

This may not work - git post-1.9.1

Using bash:

```
for remote in `git branch -r `; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

Update the branches, assuming there are no changes on your local tracking branches:

```
for remote in `git branch -r `; do git checkout $remote ; git pull; done
```

Ignore the ambiguous refname warnings, git seems to prefer the local branch as it should.

refer this :
[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)

Comment: Watch out: this answer is broken for git post-1.9.1, and will create a mess of local branches, all incorrectly tracking master