# How to migrate and synchronization source code to our own repo with only read access?

Tags: git, git-clone

I have a repo(we calls it as repo X) that maintaining by another group. For some reason I have only read access(can't add new branch) for this repo.
So I've to mirror it and migrate a same one(call repo Y) on our own server. And every day we want synchronization this repo.

But we're face a problem.

The original repo have 3 branches:
branch A,   branch B,    branch C

And the repo on our server have 2 more branches:
branch E,   branch F

Because we want to synchronization code from repo X, so we mirror it and push it to our server.
But we found that our own branch E, F is deleted.

Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Generally speaking, what we need is to have a new repo Y on our own server, and we could make our own changes on it, but still we could fetch the newest changes form the original repo X.

Comment: `git fetch upstream` seems like what you're looking for with remote set to the original repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot directly "fetch upstream" from the target repo, meaning you have to use an intermediate repo, then don't use [`push --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---mirror): deleted refs will be removed from the remote end.

Try [`git push --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---all) instead, after making sure your intermediate repo is tracking all the branches of the original repo: see [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309).

Comment: Hi, I try did so, but after I use  git push --all, I found there're only a master branch is created.

Comment: That is because you didn't create local branches first. See the last link in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried and result is ok. But seems there is a problem, that is the remote repo delete Branch A, local repo will not also delete the Branch A if you use git push --all