# Getting rid of the repository name prefix from branches

Tags: git, github

I cloned my entire GitHub repository to a local computer using:

```
git clone git@github.com:my_account_name/my_repository_name.git
```

Suppose the branches I had on the remote repository were `foo` and `bar`. When I do:

```
git branch -r
```

the remote branches stored on my local computer are listed with the names:

```
origin/foo
origin/bar
```

(And with `git branch -a`, they appear with `remotes/` further prefixed.) When I work on the branches on my local computer, I want to refer to the branches without the `origin/` prefix. For each branch, I can probably do like:

```
git branch -m origin/foo foo
```

to rename the branch, but I actually have a lot of branches, and do not want to do it manually one by one. Is there a way to get rid of these `origin/` (or `remotes/origin/`) prefix for multiple remote branches on the local computer at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `git checkout foo`. That's it.

You're not supposed to rename or work in the `origin/*` branches, they track the remote repository's state. You don't work in them directly, you create your local copies.

Checking out a branch which doesn't exist locally but does exist remotely creates this branch automatically for you, so just do a checkout but omit the `origin/` part.

Comment: Is there a way to checkout all of them (one after another) at once to just create a local branch for each of them?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches) what you're looking for?

Comment: @sawa: you can use the linked answer to do that; but in general you *shouldn't*; it does not make things any easier for you now, and eventually makes things harder for you because now you have a whole slew of local branches you constantly have to update or prune. Better to let `git fetch` update your remote-tracking branches automatically, and make local copies only when you start working on them.

Comment: I got a feeling that `git clone --mirror` suggested in an answer to the link provided by @tkausl is (close to) what I was looking for.

Comment: This does not work for the branches I have not created locally. I cannot checkout the branches without the origin/ prefix and I am getting pathspec does not match any known files. Using origin/ as prefix works fine, but keeps the prefix in the branch name.
git version 2.21.0.windows.1

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no, and you should not even try".

A *remote-tracking branch name* is not a branch, despite the name "remote-tracking branch name".  Instead, it's your Git's memory of some *other* Git's branch name.  This serves several purposes, including the ability to create your own branch names *from* these remote-tracking names.

In Git, a branch or tag name, like `master` or `v1.1`, is a device Git provides to let you assign a human-readable name to a (one, single) hash ID.  These hash IDs are usually the IDs of commits.  (The normal exception occurs with tags, which can name tag objects, which then name commits; this is how Git implements annotated tags.)

What makes (local) branch names special is that they have the unique property that you can "get on them", by running `git checkout` with a branch name.  Once you do, `git status` will say things like `on branch master`.  And—this is the *really* special trick—if you now make a *new* commit, Git will *automatically* store the new commit's hash ID in the current branch name, i.e., the one you're "on".

As another special trick, if you tell Git to get on to some branch name `B`, and branch name `B` currently *does not exist*, Git will scan your set of remote-tracking names, such as `origin/master` and `origin/B`.  If it finds *exactly one* such name, it will:

- create a new name `B`
- pointing to the same commit as `origin/B`
- and set to *track* `origin/B`

(these term are especially unfortunate: a local branch name "tracks" a "remote-tracking" branch name, which is named according to the *remote*, and yet every single one of these things is local!).

Every time you run `git fetch origin`, your Git calls up another Git, at the URL associated with the *remote* named `origin`.  The other Git tells your Git what branch names it has right now, and what commit IDs go with those names.  Your Git downloads any new commits and, at this time, updates your remote-tracking names to match their names, updating your Git's memory of what is in their Git over there.  So even if you do manage to do something with the remote-tracking names, you'll wipe out all your efforts on every `git fetch`.

Note that once you have a branch named `B`, it's totally independent of what happens to your `origin/B`, until and unless you instruct your Git to do something to re-synchronize with your `origin/B`.  You might do this after you `git fetch`, to first synchronize `origin/B` with the Git at `origin`, then to synchronize your `B` with your `origin/B`.

(Git provides the two-step "synchronize, then synchronize again" as a convenience command, `git pull`, but for anyone starting with Git, I recommend avoiding this command—it does too much, sometimes poorly; and when something fails, it leaves you in a mess you can't recover from because you don't know which step failed and cannot read the correct documentation, which is specific to that step!)

Comment: A good essay illustrating the last point is ["Git: fetch and merge, don't pull"](https://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/).

Answer (score 1):

They are remote branches. They need the `origin/` prefix, it tells the remote repo where they belong to.

On the local repo you need to create local branches to track the remote branches. There are several ways to do it:

```
git branch foo origin/foo
```

creates the local branch `foo` that points to the commit pointed by the remote branch `origin/foo` (the branch `foo` on the remote repo `origin`).

If you want to start working on `foo` then you have to `git checkout foo`. But you can combine both commands in only one:

```
git checkout -b foo
```

If there is only one remote branch named `foo`, `git checkout` identifies it (it's `origin/foo`) and internally runs the equivalent of the first two commands listed above.

If you don't need all remote branches you can remove (one by one) them using:

```
git remote -d -r origin/foo
```

`-d` is "delete", `-r` tells it that the branch is a remote branch.

You can remove more than one branch at a time but it doesn't accept wildcards. You can, however, combine `git branch --list` with `grep` to get the names of the branches to delete:

```
git branch -r --format '%(refname:lstrip=2)' | grep 'foo*' | xargs git remote -d -r
```

Replace `'foo*'` with any wildcard you need to match the desired branch names.

---

Read more about [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) and [`xargs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).

Comment: This is a much better response than the accepted one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your brach during `checkout` and use alias like this:

```
cb = !sh -c 'git checkout -b $1 origin/$1' -
```

After that you will be able run commands like:

```
git cb foo
git cb bar
```