# Centralized Git repository starting from local

Tags: git, svn, repository, centralized

Suppose I want to settle a Git repository with an SVN like workflow (so a centralized repository on an URL every developer refers to).

I understood that you can push to Bare repository without restrictions (but group rights and the likes), but you can't on a regular one without using force option. So a "SVN" like central repository should be initialized bare. **Did I understood that properly ?**

Now, I wonder what is the shortest way to generate a centralized repository out of a local folder which already has a git repository (with no clone nor remote link yet), sources files, and possibly with more than 1 branch.

For now I use the following method, but I'm not sure it's enough :

On the remote folder my_project.git :

- `git init --bare`

And now exclusively on local folder my_project with the existing repo :

- `git remote add origin url_to_my_project.git`
- `git push -u --all`

**Is this enough ?**

When I clone the centralized repo on another local place, the new repo does not seems strictly equivalent than the original local copy. When using `git branch -a` command, I have two different results, and my git knowledge is currently not enough to understand what happened.

On original local repository :

```
> git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

On local repository cloned from centralized remote :

```
> git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

**What exactly happened that the two copies doesn't look equivalent ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So a "SVN" like central repository should be initialized bare. Did I understood that properly ?
>    Pushing to a bare repository (without any working tree checked out, which might be impacted by the push) is [the best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2147741/6309).
>
> ```
> git init --bare; 
> # local: 
> git remote add origin url_to_my_project.git
> git push -u --all
> ```
>
> Is this enough ?

Yes.
Provided you have a listener: ssh daemon (as mentioned in  "[Getting Git on a Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)") or HTTPS server (used for [smart HTTP](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP))

> When I clone the centralized repo on another local place, the new repo does not seems strictly equivalent than the original local copy.
>   When using `git branch -a` command, I have two different results,

That is expected:

- The [`git push --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all) does push all branches under `refs/heads`/
  [The `-u` part](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all) adds upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and other commands.
- `git branch -a` on your second clone does list the [symbolic branch referenced by your remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12613893/6309).
  `origin/HEAD` represents [the default branch on the remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/6309) you just cloned.
  Something that the first repository (you pushed) couldn't know, since you were pushing to an empty repository (no default branch yet)

Answer (score 1):

Branches on the remote repository are renamed like `remote/<remote-name>/<branch-name>` on local copy (by default) to avoid name conflict between local and remote repositories.

If you want a SVN-like behavior (i.e. share the same branch namespace), you can edit the mapping on `.git/config` to your need:

```ini
# default configuration ('master' branch on remote corresponds to 'remotes/origin/master' branch on local)
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:example/url_to_my_project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

For example:

```ini
# SVN-like configuration ('master' branch on remote corresponds to 'master' branch on local)
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:example/url_to_my_project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

That said, it is not a recommended nor scalable way since you need to configure this mapping on each clone of the repository.

See [the refspec section on the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) and [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968256/getting-rid-of-the-repository-name-prefix-from-branches) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I do not seek for a strict SVN equivalent, just a setup which allow its workflow (pull & push to central if I use git terms). Being able to push was the most important part.