# How to recovered a deleted bitbucket repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I deleted a repository accidentally via bitbucket UI. I already had clone the project so I have it locally. When I run this command `git branch --remote`, I can see all the branches on that repository. I tried `git push --all origin` but I had the error `fatal: remote error: Repository not found`. How can I restore my repository?

Comment: create new repo with same name, push to the new repo. anyway, there is no way to restore the repo easily, branches you dont have locally will lost forever. cmiiw.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have recreated a new repository, you should:

- create local branches for all your remote tracking branches that you still have in your local repository: see "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379081/6309)"
- change your origin to the new empty repository (unless you can re-create it with the sane name/URL)
- do a `git push --all origin`

That will restore yuor repository content at the time of your last `git fetch`.

Comment: So having only cloned the master , by re creating a git repo with all those branches will do the trick?

Comment: @user3841581 You are recreating an empty repository, and use your current local repo to fill it.

Comment: I am not able to push as there is a conflict in the email. This is what I received
 `remote: Push rejected`
 `remote: refs/heads/Remote-branche:45fsdsdfsdfjf: expected committer email'myemail@email' but found initialcommiter@email.com`
 `remote:Git filter-branch allows you to rewrite the commit history`.  
I know that I can override the authors of the commit but I would like to keep them

Answer (score 0):

You can not recover it without recovering the remote branches