# How to import diffusion repository to github with complete history?

Tags: github, repository, push-diffusion

I have a diffusion repository that I would like to import to github with complete history. I tried a few options that appeared on search. Maybe someone can help what would be the easiest option to do that. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the easiest option is:

- create a (completely) empty repository on GitHub (no README, no nothing)
- go to your local repository
- add as origin the URL of your new GitHub empty repository
- push with mirror.

That is:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/<myrepo>
# if origin already existed, change it with
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/<myrepo>
git push --mirror origin
```

Comment: Thanks VonC. Remote origin already existed, so I run the second command. After pushing with mirror, I see both of my branches but only 24 commits in GitHub (out of 70 in diffusion).  For the remaining 46 commits, it gives me an option to create a pull request. I would, however, like to have the repository in the exact same state as in Diffusion. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: @Curious Is this a public repository, that I can have a look?

Comment: Unfortunately, a private repo. Just a quick question, is it supposed to push *all* branches to GitHub? In another repo, it is missing even some branches. Any alternative solutions?

Comment: @Curious Make sure your local repo has local branches for all upstream (original repo) first. Then the push --mirror will push everything. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309

Comment: Thanks. And just to be sure, does it basically push from the local repo or from the remote one? As in do I need to make sure all local branches are up to date?

Comment: @Curious push from local to the new remote origin that you have set. If your local branches are up-to-date, they will appear in the new origin repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215472/discussion-between-curious-and-vonc).