# how to get only real branch names from git to use them for a bulk change

Tags: git

I want to do some things for each branch which fits to a given criteria.

Example:

Track all branches from a specific remote:

For each branch I simply have to: `git checkout --track remotes/origin/br1`

But if I now want to do this as a bulk change, I have to write something like:

`git branch --all| grep 'remotes/origin' | xargs -n1 git checkout --track`

But this will fail for some of the found "branches" because they are not branches but symbolic-refs like `remotes/origin/HEAD` which points to `origin/master`.

As I read from other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3099621/878532 I see that the people are manually filtering out wrong refs with "grep -v HEAD" here. But this is not what I expect, because here I have to know that HEAD is a symbolic-ref and not a branch.

So I need something to find only real branches. I already take a look on `git for-each-ref --format <...>` and was in hope that `objtype` give me some hint but I did not get anything which helps.

Q: How I can get a list of real branches to use them for a bulk change.

Answer (score 0):

`HEAD` symbolic ref is very annoying in this case, but you can use `rev-parse` with [`--symbolic-full-name`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---symbolic-full-name) to get rid of it and obtain the actual branch it references. In the end, I would do:

```
git branch -rl 'origin/*' | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name | sort -u
```

`git branch` options:

- `-r` returns only remote branches
- `-l` lets you specify a pattern that selected branch names will match.

I used `awk` to keep only the first token, discarding `-> origin_branch_name`. `sort -u` is necessary here because the branch pointed by `HEAD` is clearly duplicated now.