# Error merging branches that have name with slash

Tags: git, github

I need to merge a branch from a different repository (project1) to my current empty repository, therefore I was using the command:
`git merge --allow-unrelated-histories project1/<branch name>`

project1 has 3 branches:

```
remotes/origin/feature/add-logging
remotes/origin/feature/create-awesome
remotes/origin/master
```

When the branch's name is **feature/add-logging** so the command is:
`git merge --allow-unrelated-histories project1/feature/add-logging`

Then GIT said:
`merge: project1/feature/add-logging - not something we can merge`

I think the problem is the slash in the branch name because I can successfully merge the branch master with the command `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories project1/master`

How could I fix this? Thank you so much

Comment: Run `git branch -a`; include it and its output into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project1/master` refers to the branch `master` of the remote named `project1`.

But in your case, you have fetched the only local branch of `project1`: `master`.

The other branches from project1 are remote tracking branches (`origin/xxx`), tracking the remote "`origin`" from which `project1` was initially cloned.

You need to make those tracking branches as local branch in `project1` first, before a fetch from `project1` in your current repo allows you to merge `project1/anyBranch`.

See "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309)", to be done in `project1`, before fetching (again) `project1` in your repository.
Then, in said repository, you will be able to merge any `project/xxx` you want.

Answer (score 1):

That can't be the problem:

```
$ git log -5 --pretty='git branch test/%h %h' | sh -x
+ git branch test/20ae7113be 20ae7113be                   
+ git branch test/9b09ab0cd7 9b09ab0cd7           
+ git branch test/225bc32a98 225bc32a98                                                                                
+ git branch test/b06a5047ee b06a5047ee
+ git branch test/f7cd3c0832 f7cd3c0832
$ git clone -ns . `mktemp -d`
[…]
$ cd $_
$ git checkout test/f7cd3c0832
[…]
$ git merge origin/test/20ae7
merge: origin/test/20ae7 - not something we can merge                                                                  
$ git merge origin/test/20ae7113be
[… the usual merge output, it works …]
$
```

So I think you typo'd your branch name.