# Syncing Bitbucket to Github not Bringing over All Branches

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to sync our repository on Bitbucket with a fresh repository on Github, such that when I push code to origin (Bitbucket), it pushes that commit on to the "mirrored" Github repository.

To do this, I created the Github repo and set up the ssh keys etc.
I then added a Pipleline to Bitbucket called `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` which has the following code:

```
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - git push --mirror git@github.com:orgname/nameofrepo.git
```

This brought over every commit and tag and the branch which I was currently on, but it did not bring over the other branches.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that they all start with the word `origin`, but that is just a theory based on the fact that the only branch which did come across did not start with `origin`.

I've also tried a variation where I use:

```
      - step:
          clone:
            depth: full # want all so can push all (maybe can optimise this in future?)
          name: 'Sync push on branch to github'
          script:
            - git remote add sync git@github.com:orgname/nameofrepo.git
            - git push sync --all --force
            - git push sync --tags --force
```

Exact same result.

This is what other people (on blogs etc) have been doing to achieve this and I'm assuming they are trying to sync more than just `main`.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you push --mirror to push all branches, you might need first, in your Bitbucket pipeline, to add a step where you make a local branch out of all the remote tracking `origin/xxx` branches.

I proposed a [one-liner before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309) to do that.

```
for i in $(git for-each-ref --format=%(refname:short) \
  --no-merged=origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin); do \
    git switch --track $i; \
done
```

Once your Bitbucket has cloned and created all local branch, you can proceed with a push --mirror.

Note: that would necessitate a Bitbucket pipeline [using Docker images as build environments](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-docker-images-as-build-environments/), running a [default Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/default-image/).
That would include a recent Git 2.39.1.
The OP confirm in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251982/discussion-between-vonc-and-onefootswill) using a build environment with... Git 1.9.1 (March 2014).

Using the default Atlassian image solves this, as it comes with the latest Git 2.39.1

```yaml
image: atlassian/default-image:4.20230131
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      script:
      - 'for i in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --no-merged=origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin); do echo $i; git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/${i#origin/} || git switch --track $i; git branch -l; done; git branch -lvv; git push --mirror git@github.com:you/repo.git'
```

The script in multiple lines:

```bash
for i in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" \
                --no-merged=origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin); do 
  echo $i; 
  git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/${i#origin/} || git switch --track $i; 
  git branch -l; 
done; 
git branch -lvv; 
git push --mirror git@github.com:you/repo.git
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a weird error. 1st, I had to add parenthesis around the value passed to `--format` . But the error I'm getting is `error: unknown option no-merged`. I replaced the = operator with a space and get the same error. The command works fine locally, but not on Bitbucket cloud.

Comment: @onefootswill Strange: it is a [valid option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---no-mergedltobjectgt). What Git version are you using?

Comment: Indeed. I've tried to ascertain that. [This page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/what-version-of-git-do-you-support-1168845106.html) seems to indicate that Bitbucket keeps up to date in terms of Git versions. So, I'm a bit confused by that error as well. And I've confirmed it works locally.

Comment: Also, I just tried putting the whole line between apostrophes (like a string) as I wanted to eliminate the notion that the colon before `short` was the issue. Apparently the colon is fine, as there is no space after it. Worth trying.

Comment: @onefootswill did you try using it as one line, instead of multiple lines as I put it in the answer?

Comment: Yeah. That's the first step I took. Made it a one-liner. Your solution looks really good and makes me think it would solve the problem. So I'm quite disappointed with Bitbucket pipelines.

Comment: @onefootswill Can you try, in the bitbucket pipeline, to run a command like `git --version`?

Comment: Great idea **slaps forehead**. And I think we have our answer. The version is 1.9.1 ! I guess I need to figure out a way of doing the same thing without that convenient option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251982/discussion-between-vonc-and-onefootswill).

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository) to mirror my repo.  My working `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file looks like this:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        clone:
          enabled: false
        script:
          - git clone --bare git@bitbucket.org:<source>/<repo>.git
          - cd <repo>.git
          - git push --mirror git@github.com:<destination>/<repo>.git
```

Setting the clone "enabled" option to false will prevent bitbucket from automatically cloning the repo as part of the step (which it does automatically).  [See documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/git-clone-behavior/#Enabled).