# Having issues logging into GitLab from Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, gitlab

I am trying to import my gitlab repository in Azure DevOps, but I am getting below error. Although URL and authorization both things are correct, Can you please suggest alternative to import git repository in Azure DevOps.

```
Import request cannot be processed due to one of the following reasons:
Clone URL is incorrect
Clone URL requires authorization
```

Contacted to administrator and tried with admin rights, still not able to connect to git repository.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be:

- create an empty private repository in Azure DevOps
- clone it locally
- import locally your repository in it (`git remote add repo ../path/to/gitlab/local/clone` + `git fetch` + [create a local branch for every remote tracking branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309))
- push back ([`git push --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror))

That would take care of the repository itself (you can add options to import tags as well)

If you can clone your own Azure DevOps *private* repository, then surely the authentication won't be an issue.