# Restoring locally deleted GitHub branch with ongoing PR

Tags: git, github

I accidentally locally deleted a GitHub branch with an ongoing PR. How can I restore it locally so that I can continue making and pushing modifications to the PR?

Comment: Use the reflog. `git reflog`

Comment: I am not sure if it will work, it happened like a week ago or something. How would I formulate the command in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for here:
[How to download a branch with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294313/how-to-download-a-branch-with-git)

```
git checkout -t origin/branch-name
```

Comment: sadly, this doesn't answer the question

Comment: It does, it allows you to restore on your local machine a branch that you had previously deleted in your local repository and continue with an ongoing PR.

Comment: That's not the question though, since it won't continue from the local commits.

Comment: It will continue with the local commits, the -t stands for track, so if you make a change locally and commit it, it will go directly to the PR. I have tried it and it worked.