# How do i switch to an 'unstable' branch using git?

Tags: git

I'm testing out a package (git clone git://guacamole.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/guacamole/guacamole)

This project has two branches: 'master' and 'unstable'

How can I get the 'unstable' branch ?

Sorry for the dummy question, but 'git branch' only shows 'master'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clone all remote branches with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git) - the branch is there, you just need to see it with `git branch -a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `git branch -a` to list all branches and `git checkout unstable` to get the unstable branch

edit: this assumes you have already cloned the repo

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually check out the unstable branch from the repo.

`git checkout -b unstable origin/unstable`