# BitBucket: My Cloned repo does not include other branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working on a project at work and have uploaded the project to a private bitbucket repo, i  have cloned the repo on my home machine, but i only get the master branch and not my other branch **develop**.

How can i make sure that this local repo matches the origin/remote version so i able to work on this branch

EDIT:
no sooner that i post i finally find an answer typical [A good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git)

Comment: please post your answer as an Answer (below) to make it obvious that your problem has been solved ;)

Comment: I will when i am allowed to just wanted to make sure i let people know rather than waste time as well as for others needing an answer :-)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I clone all remote branches with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git)