# Update all branches in git

Tags: git, github, fetch, git-branch

I forked a repo: https://github.com/CruceGameDevel/CruceGame and I cloned my copy to local machine:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/MihaiPro/CruceGame
```

If I run:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

Why it show only master branch? I tried `git remote update` and `git fetch --all` but doesn't work. What I need to do? Maybe I did something wrong, so please give me correct steps of cloning a forked repo.
Thanks!

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
git branch -a
```

Remote-tracking branches are not listed in `git branch` without `-a`.

Comment: Alternativly you can use `git branch -r`, which will just show the remote branches but not the local ones. Also you can take a look at the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) for further information.