# git clone all branches bash script as git alias

Tags: git, bash, git-branch, git-clone, git-alias

I would like to create a **git alias** that ***clones all branches***.

We have the bash script, thanks to this post:
[How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Here is the bash script (multi-line version):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do
        git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"
    done
```

(one line version):

```
    git branch -a | grep -v HEAD | perl -ne 'chomp($_); s|^\*?\s*||; if (m|(.+)/(.+)| && not $d{$2}) {print qq(git branch --track $2 $1/$2\n)} else {$d{$_}=1}' | csh -xfs
```

Let's call the git alias `git cloneallbranches`

I have tried setting both one-line and multi-line versions using:

`$ git config --global alias.cloneallbranches '...'`

and tried to paste both versions into my .gitconfig file unsuccessfully (I have other git aliases, but none are bash scripts).

Can someone help me alter a bash script, so that I can paste it into my  .gitconfig file, to make the git alias works properly?

Thank you.

---

**ANSWER:**

Running a *separate bash script* as a "git alias" answer in reply below.

However, for those who want a quick way to add a git alias, `$ git clone-all-branches` here is an answer:

- Thanks to updated answer here: [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Create a "git alias" which will run a script:

`$ git config --global alias.clone-all-branches '! git branch -a | sed -n "/\/HEAD /d; /\/master$/d; /remotes/p;" | xargs -L1 git checkout -t'`

Now you can run (from any directory that has a git repo):

`$ git clone-all-branches`

Comment: You must start the alias command with a bang `!` if it's not a git subcommand. So `!git branch -a | grep...`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @g-sliepen suggestion, I did the following:

For Ubuntu:

**#1** Go to home directory:

```
`$ cd ~`
```

Note: Should be same directory as .gitconfig and .bashrc files, which you will need in a shortly.

**#2** Create a new file, a bash script, that we will execute later (make sure you are in the home directory):

```
`$ touch .gitcloneallbranches.sh`
```

Open the file:

```
`$ subl .gitcloneallbranches.sh`
```

Paste and save the following inside your file:

```
# Bash script that we will execute as an "alias" either as a "git alias" or a "bash alias"
#!/bin/bash
git branch -a | grep -v HEAD | perl -ne 'chomp($_); s|^\*?\s*||; if (m|(.+)/(.+)| && not $d{$2}) {print qq(git branch --track $2 $1/$2\n)} else {$d{$_}=1}' | csh -xfs`
```

**#3** Give that file the permissions it needs to be executed:

```
`$ chmod u+x .gitcloneallbranches.sh`
```

Use script as **#4** a "git alias" **-OR-** as **#5** a "bash alias"

**#4** Create a "git alias" which will allow you to run this script as a git command:

- [Skip to #5 if you prefer a bash alias]

PICK ONE of *A* **-OR-** *B* ways to create the **git alias** (the "bash alias" is #5):

(A: via terminal)

`$ git config --global alias.clone-all-branches '!sh ~/.gitcloneallbranches.sh'`

(OR, B: or, add alias directly in .gitconfig file:)

In home directory, open .gitconfig:

`$ subl .gitconfig`

Under the [alias] section, paste the following:

`[alias]
clone-all-branches = !sh ~/.gitcloneallbranches.sh`

***Try our git alias!***

Go to directory where your git repo resides.

- (Note: If a repo does not already exist, do a normal "git clone git@..." command, which will clone the master branch first, before our new "git clone-all-branches" command will work.)

View the current branches:

`$ git branch`  // Should be the current branches available

Try our new git alias:

`$ git clone-all-branches`

View branches again:

`$ git branch` // All branches now available!

**#5** Alternatively, create a "bash alias" to run our .gitcloneallbranches.sh script:

- [Instead of #4, open .bashrc (or .bash_profile or .profile)]:

`$ subl .bashrc`

Inside that file, add an "alias" by adding the following:

`# Adds ability to clone all branches of a repo, by typing 'clone-all-branches' in any directory with a git repo:
alias clone-all-branches='source ~/.gitcloneallbranches.sh'`

***Try our bash alias!***

Go to directory where your git repo resides.

- (Note: If a repo does not already exist, do a normal "git clone git@..." command, which will clone the master branch first, before our new "clone-all-branches" command will work.)

View the current branches:

`$ git branch`  // Should be the current branches available

Try our new git alias:

`$ clone-all-branches`

View branches again:

`$ git branch` // All branches now available!

Comment: Just a word of warning: the `chomp` function in the perl script will remove all leading words that end in a slash, so if your branch names include a slash (eg. feat/some-feature), it well end up being some-feature locally.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way: just create a script called `git-cloneallbranches` that lives somewhere in your `$PATH` (for example, if you have `$HOME/bin` in your `$PATH`, that might be a good place). When you run `git cloneallbranches`, it will then automatically run your script.