# How to clone all branches on the fork when cloned to computer?

Tags: git, branch, git-fork

I have a fork and i have used clone command to clone the repository in to my computer.Now it is showing me 1 branch but the fork is having 4 branches.

Series of steps i followed:

```
$ git branch
* master

HOME@H MINGW32 ~/Desktop/KIRAN/VITacademics-Enhancement-Suite (master)
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/rahulkapoor90/VITacademics-Enhancement-Suite

HOME@H MINGW32 ~/Desktop/KIRAN/VITacademics-Enhancement-Suite (master)
$ git remote remove jwasham

HOME@H MINGW32 ~/Desktop/KIRAN/VITacademics-Enhancement-Suite (master)
$ git fetch upstream
From https://github.com/rahulkapoor90/VITacademics-Enhancement-Suite
 * [new branch]      Development -> upstream/Development
 * [new branch]      master      -> upstream/master
 * [new branch]      material-ui -> upstream/material-ui
```

Now i entered command git branch -a it showed in different colors.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/Development
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/material-ui
  remotes/upstream/Development
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/material-ui
```

But these branches are not showing in default branches when i enter `git branch`.But if i checkout any branch it is detaching from the HEAD.

How to fix this problem?Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

You've only one local branch called `master`. Other branches start with `remotes/origin/*` or `remotes/upstream/*` are remote.

If you want to create a local branch having changes/commits of a remote branch, then just checkout with branch-name. Or, create a new branch & pull the remote branch into your new-branch

```
  $ git checkout -b Development origin/Development

 Or,
  $ git checkout master          
  $ git checkout -b Development
  $ git pull origin Development
```