# GitPython How to clone all branches?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I found this [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754797/7024242) script, which accomplishes the same task but in Bash.

Working with GitPython to create a complete backup of a repository, can't seem to figure out how to get all the branches to show without having to manual checkout them.

```
Repo.clone_from(repo, folder)
```

I'm using this line in a loop to copy all the files from the repos.

Comment: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone_from has multi_options argument, in theory must be possible set multi_options=['--mirror'] for cloning full copy, but it not works for me and I have no time for investigation.

Comment: @AlexeyShrub better to use kwargs: mirror=True (see my updated answer)

Comment: All branches can be listed using "Repo.remotes.origin.refs"

Answer (score 4):

I have recently stumbled upon this thread, but have not found any solution, so I have brewed my own. It is better than nothing, neither optimal nor pretty, but at least it works:

```
# Clone master
repo = Repo.clone_from('https://github.com/user/stuff.git', 'work_dir', branch='master')

# Clone the other branches as needed and setup them tracking the remote
for b in repo.remote().fetch():
    repo.git.checkout('-B', b.name.split('/')[1], b.name)
```

Explanation:

1. Clone the master branch
2. Fetch the remote branch names
3. Checkout branches and create them as needed

PS: I think Gitpython has not got a built-in method to do this with `clone_from`.

**UPDATE**:

`no_single_branch=True` option in GitPyhton is equal to `--no-single-branch` in git CLI (other 'valueless' arguments can also supplied with `True` value)

```
repo = Repo.clone_from('https://github.com/user/stuff.git', 'work_dir', branch='master', no_single_branch=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for b in Repo.clone_from(repo, folder).remote[0].fetch():
   print(b.name)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

    for b in Repo.clone_from(repo, folder).remote[0].fetch():


I am getting this error currently when using this code

Comment: for b in Repo.clone_from(repo, folder).remotes.origin.fetch():
            print b.name

This will print out all the names of the branches, still having trouble copying them to the folders though.