# git clone all remote branches

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have a repository in github with X number of branches and a repository in a closed network.

I need to move all of the repository to the one on the closed network. How do I clone all the branches (not just the default master), so I could then push it to the closed-network one with all the branches existing.

Entering the repo binary is not the issue here.

I want the same result as if I cloned my repo and did `git branch` to each branch, so it would be initialized locally.

Comment: [Here is the detail answer click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 3):

If it's ok to *not* create the remote branch refs, and if the clone can be "bare" (no default working tree), then you can use

```
git clone --mirror url
```

But you said you want the same result as cloning and then checking out each branch.  Taken literally, that would mean a non-bare repo that has both the remote refs and the local branches.  To do that you could do this:

First, clone normally and cd into the new clone

```
git clone url new-repo
cd new-repo
```

Now force detached head state to ensure no "current branch" problems

```
git checkout `git rev-parse HEAD`
```

Now get the local branches set up

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

And now of course you can check out whatever branch you should be on, e.g.

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

to get all branches from remote.

**Bash script :**

```
#!/bin/bash

for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do
    git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"
done
```

or

**One line code :**

`git branch -a | grep -v HEAD | perl -ne 'chomp($_); s|^\*?\s*||; if (m|(.+)/(.+)| && not $d{$2}) {print qq(git branch --track $2 $1/$2\n)} else {$d{$_}=1}' | csh -xfs`

Answer (score 1):

Once created something like that.
Hopefully it still works.
Perhaps it could help you:
https://github.com/srfrnk/fetch-all

Answer (score 0):

There's a `git-clone` option `--mirror` which sets up all remotely tracked branches. But, `--mirror` also implies `--bare` option, ie. the clone will will not be created as a working copy and you cannot checkout the branches. Therefore the directory is changed to a working directory afterwards.

```
$ git clone --mirror original-repo.git /path/cloned-directory/.git
$ cd /path/cloned-directory
$ git config --bool core.bare false
$ git checkout anybranch
```

[Git FAQ: How do I clone a repository with all remotely tracked branches?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_clone_a_repository_with_all_remotely_tracked_branches.3F)

Comment: Careful: if you use the four lines shown above, your `fetch` configuration entry will still be set up to *overwrite* local branches.