# Bash script assistance with find

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script called by a daily cron schedule that will cycle all sub directories looking for a .git directory, run a `git pull --all` on that repository to update the repo and grab any new branches, track those branches, and then move on to the next repo. I'm a bash script beginner and familiar with some linux. My problem is the for loop which I found at [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git) but doesn't seem to run properly now that I've introduced it into my script and the call to `cd ${line}..` which doesn't seem to work as anticipated. I'm wondering what i've done wrong and some direction on how to fix it. Thank You.

My current script gitcron.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d -print > .gitrepos

while read -r line; do
  cd ${line}/..
  git pull --all
  for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do
     git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"
  done
done < ".gitrepos"
```

.gitrepos generated file:

```
./codeigniter/.git
./magento/.git
./magento2/.git
```

My problem:

```
gitcron.sh: line 6: cd: ./magento2/.git/..: No such file or directory
fatal: it does not make sense to create 'HEAD' manually
error: unknown switch `>'
```

Comment: Why make the script more complex? Replace `.` by `$(pwd)` and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have changed the working directory (and keep changing) with `cd ${line}/..` i.e. going to the parent of the `{line}`. Everything is done within teh same shell session. After first run, the directory would be changed to the parent of the first value of `line` variable, so next run(s) would (prsumably) fail because of failing to find the parent (and hence `.git` would not also be present).

To solve this, you can:

- Use absolute paths to the directories in `find`:

  ```
  find /foo/bar/ ...
  ```

  and then use `while` as is now.
- Or run `cd` and successive block(s) in a subshell:

  ```
  while ...; do (cd ...; ...); done <file
  ```

---

As a side note, (always) quote your variable expansions to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mentioned in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you've already changed directory to first repo i.e. `codeigniter` using `cd` in your `while` loop. After that your script is not going back to parent directory using `cd -` at the end.

You can even avoid temporary file creation by using process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do
  cd "$line"/..
  git pull --all

  while read -r branch; do
     git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"
  done < <(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$')

  cd -
done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d -print0)
```

Comment: I'm getting `syntax error near unexpected token '<'` on line `done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d -print0)` OS: CentOS 7 x64

Comment: You should execute script as: `bash ./gitcron.sh`

Comment: @anubhava Better shebang: `#! /usr/bin/env bash` in gitcron.sh.

Comment: I thought sh and bash were similar but come to find out there are some differences. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: Yes indeed there are many differences. I suggested `-print0` because that will support directory names with whitespaces and special meta characters as well. Also I notices question was tagged as `bash` so suggested a `bash` solution. Let me know if using `bash` is a problem then I can suggest `sh` only script also.

Answer (score 1):

As other users have already posted, the problem seems to be not using absolute directories and `cd`ing twice.

You could simplify your script by getting rid of the temp file and using `pushd` and `popd` as opposed to `cd some/path`, `cd -`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -uo pipefail

find . -maxdepth 2 -name ".git" -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' repo; do
    # Use bash parameter substitution to remove .git from end of path
    pushd "${repo%.git}" >/dev/null
    # Could also use dirname to get the parent directory
    #pushd "$( dirname "$repo" )" >/dev/null
    # Now in correct directory; run all git commands"
    # git ...
    popd >/dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try the same find command, but with absolute paths:

```
find $(pwd) -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d -print > .gitrepos
```

That way, `cd` will access those folder through their full and complete path.
Even if your first `cd` changed the current path, it won't maater.