# Gitlab - Get SSH Key For Non-Master Branch

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab, git-branch

I'm trying to avoid using the git command line, simply using the SSH key given in Gitlab and using that SSH key to import to Intellij Idea IDE.
I have a project with two branches: "master" and "development." under Gitlab's "Project" page, there is an SSH key, but it seems to only refer to the master branch; when checked out into the Intellij IDE, it only gets the master files. Is there a separate SSH key for the development branch? How can I access and check it out?

Answer (score 0):

SSH key provides you SSH access to the repository - so with the key, you can clone all branches.

The thing is that by default `git clone` clones only the [master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git),  Since IDE just uses a command line git, it clones master only as well.

To get developer branch to your repository, you could use the branches widget and checkout the remote branch as the local one. If you do not see the remote branch in the list, do `VCS - Git - Fetch`