# Updating and repairing LFS when migrating repositories from Github to selfhosted Gitlab

Tags: git, bash, github, gitlab

For my company I have to migrate all our company repositories from Github to our self hosted Gitlab-Server.

The main problem I have is that we use [Git-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for the most of our repositories.

Therefore when cloning a repository I have to repair the Git-LFS by running

```
git lfs fetch --all
git lfs push remoteOnGitlab
```

I'm writing on a script for that - since it are a lot of repositories - using the Github API to work off a list of all our repositories:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

###_Adjust those_#######################################################
githubUrlStart="https://"
githubLink="github.com/<orgaName>"
githubApiLink="api.github.com/orgs/<orgaName>/repos"

# maxRepoCount is needed if the organisation has more than 30 repos
# otherwise only the first 30 repos would be mirrored
maxRepoCount="200"

gitlabUrlStart="http://"
gitlabLink="<gitlabURL>/<groupName>"
########################################################################


###_Get Sensible Data at runtime_###
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
                                           
echo -n "${bold}Github Username: ${normal}"
read -e githubName
echo -n "${bold}Github Password: ${normal}"
read -e -s githubPassword
echo ""
echo -n "${bold}Gitlab Username: ${normal}"
read -e gitlabName
echo -n "${bold}Gitlab Password: ${normal}"
read -e -s gitlabPassword

###_Add folder for cloned git repos_###
mkdir gits

###_GET JSON of all REPOS from the Github API_###
# writes output to file test for later use
curl "$githubUrlStart${githubName//\"}:${githubPassword//\"}@${githubApiLink//\"}?per_page=${maxRepoCount//\"}" > test 

###_Get URLS and NAME_###
#  -> http://xmodulo.com/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html #
NAMES=$(cat test | jq ".[] | .name");

###_Transform into Array_###
NAMES_ARRAY=()

COUNT=0
for name in $NAMES
do
    NAMES_ARRAY[$COUNT]=$name
                             
    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
done


###_Clone each repo local and use it to repair git lfs_###                                                                                            
COUNT=0                                                                                       
for reponame in "${NAMES_ARRAY[@]}"                                                           
do                                                                                            
    ###_Build full link for cloning_###
    fulllink="$githubUrlStart$githubName:$githubPassword@$githubLink/${reponame//\"}"     
                                                                                              
    ###_Clone from github using git lfs_###
    git lfs clone "${fulllink//\"}" "gits/${reponame//\"}"
                                                                                              
    ###_Enter folder of cloned repository_###                                                   
    cd "gits/${reponame//\"}"
                                                                                              
    ###_repair git lfs_###
    # get lfs from github
    git lfs fetch --all
    
    # add the remote for gitlab
    gitlabRemote="$gitlabUrlStart$gitlabName:$gitlabPassword@$gitlabLink/${reponame//\"}.git" 
    git remote add gitlab "${gitlabRemote//\"}"
    
    # Just for security remove the github remote                                                  
    git remote remove origin                                                                  
    
    # Push lfs to the gitlab remote
    git lfs push gitlab --all                                                                 
       
    ##_leave folder!_##                                                                       
    cd ../..          #                                                                       
   
    ##_remove folder to save disk space_##                                                    
    rm -rf gits/${reponame//\"}
                                                                                              
    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
done

###_Remove the gits folder_####
rm -rf gits
```

My problem here:
It seems this works fine only once, but the repositories get not updated to the newest state if I run the script over them again. Also I'm not sure but I guess it will only work on the master branch so far.

**What do I have to change in order to allways get the newest state of the git repo from github also on gitlab?** (After running it I still have the state of from 2 months ago on Gitlab...)

---

#### Alternative

I also have seen another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7216269/7111561) which apparently would handle the multibranch problem:

```
git clone --mirror path/to/original path/to/dest/.git
cd path/to/dest
git config --bool core.bare false
git checkout anybranch
```

which I probably also could combine with

```
git push --mirrow path/to/otherRemote
```

as mentioned there in the comments.

This would ofcourse be way simplier .. BUT:
**Is this compatible with LFS?** let's say e.g. as

```
git lfs clone --mirrow /originOnGithub /localFolder
cd /localFolder
git lfs fetch --all
git lfs push --mirrow /remoteOnGitlab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was: **Yes it is!**

But I had a very stupid typo: ofcourse it is **`--mirror`** not `--mirrow`

So now for each project a run

```
git lfs clone --mirror /originOnGithub /localFolder
cd /localFolder
git lfs fetch --all
git lfs push --mirror /remoteOnGitlab
```

and it repairs the LFS files **AND** updates all branches in the repository on the Gitlab-Server.